# Problem executing Processing Vector Grid algorithm in a standalone script

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing, vector-grid, standalone

I have the following piece of code which I execute within QGIS 2.8.6

```
import processing
import ogr
restrLayer = QgsVectorLayer("/home/usr/Desktop/trial/EligibleAreas_polygons_filtered.shp", "EligibleAreas_polygons_filtered", "ogr")
if not restrLayer.isValid(): 
    print "Restrictions Layer Failed To Load"
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(restrLayer)
cellsize = 1000 
xmin = (restrLayer.extent().xMinimum()) 
xmax = (restrLayer.extent().xMaximum()) 
ymin = (restrLayer.extent().yMinimum()) 
ymax = (restrLayer.extent().yMaximum()) 

extent = str(xmin)+ ',' + str(xmax)+ ',' +str(ymin)+ ',' +str(ymax) 
grid1 = "/home/usr/Desktop/trial/grid1.shp"
processing.runalg('qgis:vectorgrid', extent, cellsize, cellsize, 0, grid1)
```

and it works fine. When I create a standalone script and try to do the exact same thing outside of QGIS I have the following code:

```
import qgis
from osgeo import gdal
from osgeo import ogr

from gdalconst import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.analysis import * 
from qgis.gui import *

import sys
import glob
import re 
import os, fnmatch
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma
import math 

qgisprefix = '/usr'

# configure paths for QGIS 
os.environ['PATH'] = qgisprefix+'/bin'
os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = qgisprefix+'/lib'
sys.path.insert(0, qgisprefix+'/share/qgis/python')
sys.path.insert(1, qgisprefix+'/share/qgis/python/plugins')

# disable QGIS debug messages
os.environ['QGIS_DEBUG'] = '-1'

# configure QGIS paths
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(qgisprefix, True)

# initalise QGIS (load providers)
QgsApplication.initQgis()

# create a new application object
# without this importing processing causes the following error:
# QPixmap: Must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice
app = QgsApplication([], True)

from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
from processing.tools import *
print Processing.getAlgorithm("qgis:vectorgrid")

#add the restrictions layer 
restrLayer = QgsVectorLayer("/home/usr/Desktop/trial/EligibleAreas_polygons_filtered.shp", "EligibleAreas_polygons_filtered", "ogr")
if not restrLayer.isValid(): 
   print "Restrictions Layer Failed To Load"
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(restrLayer)

cellsize = 1000 

xmin = (restrLayer.extent().xMinimum()) 
xmax = (restrLayer.extent().xMaximum()) 
ymin = (restrLayer.extent().yMinimum()) 
ymax = (restrLayer.extent().yMaximum()) 

extent = str(xmin)+ ',' + str(xmax)+ ',' +str(ymin)+ ',' +str(ymax)  

grid1 = "/home/usr/Desktop/trial/grid1.shp"
processing.runalg('qgis:vectorgrid', extent, cellsize, cellsize, 0, grid1)
```

I get no output, so no grid1.shp. From `print Processing.getAlgorithm("qgis:vectorgrid")`  I get: 
`ALGORITHM: Vector grid
    EXTENT <ParameterExtent>
    STEP_X <ParameterNumber>
    STEP_Y <ParameterNumber>
    TYPE <ParameterSelection>
    OUTPUT <OutputVector>`

so the needed algorithm from processing is found but for some reason the output layer is not created. I also checked the extent I get from the standalone script and it is the same as what I have in the python console (so the layer is loaded correctly). What could be the reason why I am not getting an output?

Comment: Probably an editing issue when posting but there's an extra double quotation mark in your 2nd last line: `grid1 = ""/home/usr/Desktop/trial/grid1.shp"`.

Comment: Sorry, it was an error when pasting the code. This is not the problem , but thanks anyway. I corrected the code above

Comment: Try replacing your last line `processing.runalg('qgis:vectorgrid', extent, cellsize, cellsize, 0, grid1)` with `general.runalg('qgis:vectorgrid', extent, cellsize, cellsize, 0, grid1)`

Comment: Still not working

Comment: I get the following error when I do general.runalg(.....): " 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mapCanvas'
See log for more details"

Comment: Try changing your `import` ordering according to this post: [Why the order of imports matters in a standalone PyQGIS processing script?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131059/why-the-order-of-imports-matters-in-a-standalone-pyqgis-processing-script). In other words, put `from PyQt4.QtGui import *` and `from PyQt4.QtCore import *` after `from qgis.gui import *`. You could also try moving `QgsApplication.initQgis()` **after** `app = QgsApplication([], True)`.

Answer (score 2):

**Why it fails**

`qgis:vectorgrid` algorithm is tied to QGIS application because it uses the `iface` object (see [line 76 of the script](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/release-2_8/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/VectorGrid.py#L76)). It depends on the Coordinate Reference System (CRS) from an existing map canvas. In the error you were getting (`'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mapCanvas' See log for more details.`) `NoneType` object is the `iface` object, which does not exist because QGIS is not running.

In a standalone scenario we don't usually have a map canvas nor an `iface` object available (although it is certainly possible, see for example [this post](http://geotux.tuxfamily.org/index.php/en/component/k2/item/229-cargando-plugins-de-quantum-gis-en-el-visor-de-pyqgis)).

**Solution**

Fortunately, QGIS offers an analog algorithm to create vector grids, it is called `qgis:creategrid` (also available in [QGIS 2.8](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/release-2_8/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/Grid.py)). The Create Grid algorithm is much better than `qgis:vectorgrid` because it doesn't depend on an existing map canvas. Instead, it receives the CRS of the output grid as an additional parameter. You could get such CRS from your  `restrLayer` layer and call the algorithm in this way:

```
crs = restrLayer.crs().authid()
general.runalg('qgis:creategrid', 1, extent, cellsize, cellsize, crs, grid1 )
```

*NOTE: The parameter `1` corresponds to a rectangular (polygon) grid. An example of the crs parameter may be 'EPSG:3115'.*

I have tested the following standalone script using QGIS 2.14.8, I hope it also works for you (QGIS v2.8.6):

```
# Prepare the environment
import sys
from qgis.core import QgsApplication, QgsVectorLayer, QgsMapLayerRegistry
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
app = QApplication([])
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr", True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()

# Prepare processing framework
sys.path.append('/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins')
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
from processing.tools import general

restrLayer = QgsVectorLayer("/my/own/data/file.shp", "EligibleAreas_polygons_filtered", "ogr")
if not restrLayer.isValid():
    print "Restrictions Layer Failed To Load"
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(restrLayer)
cellsize = 1000
xmin = (restrLayer.extent().xMinimum())
xmax = (restrLayer.extent().xMaximum())
ymin = (restrLayer.extent().yMinimum())
ymax = (restrLayer.extent().yMaximum())

extent = str(xmin)+ ',' + str(xmax)+ ',' +str(ymin)+ ',' +str(ymax)
grid1 = "/tmp/grid1.shp"
crs = restrLayer.crs().authid()
general.runalg('qgis:creategrid', 1, extent, cellsize, cellsize, crs, grid1 )

# Exit applications
QgsApplication.exitQgis()
QApplication.exit()
```